# string replace not escaping?

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I want to replace $_SERVER['DB_NAME'] with just the word test using sed. I cannot figure it out. I am escaping the $ and brackets...why am I not getting the correct result?

```
echo "\$_SERVER['DB_NAME']" | sed 's/\$_SERVER\['DB_NAME'\]/test/g'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
echo "\$_SERVER['DB_NAME']" | sed "s/\$_SERVER\['DB_NAME'\]/test/g"
```

or

```
echo "\$_SERVER['DB_NAME']" | sed 's/\$_SERVER\['"'"'DB_NAME'"'"'\]/test/g'
```

Comment: I feel stupid. So simple a solution. Most sed examples are written with single quotes so I got in the habbit of writing it that way. Making a double quote makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're using single quotes for both the sed command and the `'DB_NAME'`. Change the quotes around the sed command line to double quotes or escape the inner quotes.